# Rating model Django

Tags: python, django

i stuck at Raiting model for my project (question-answer site, like stackoverflow). I used this guid from Tango with Django http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/ajax.html to add like button with ajax. Then I decided to create special model for likes and solutions. I have no idea, how can I can do it. 
First of all i try to do this

```
class Rating(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    resolve = models.IntegerField(default=0)


url(r'add_like/(?P<answer_pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.add_like, name='add_like'),


def add_like(request, answer_pk):

    if request.POST:
        ans_rait = Rating.objects.get(answer=answer_pk)
        ans_rait.like += 1
        ans_rait.save()

    return redirect(reverse(get_question))
```

In my question page, i display question model and answers in loop

```
{% for answer in answers %}
    <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
        {{ answer.text }}   
    </div>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <form method = "post" action = "{% url 'add_like' %}">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"> like | {{ answer.rating.like }} 
        </button>
    </form>
    {% endif %}
```

Please give at least understand the logic of adding like in loop. I tried many things but did not understand how to do it

**Update**   I tried user 'Hybrid' solutions:
when i click like-button, i have exception: "local variable 'ans_rait' referenced before assignment".
When i post js script in browser console and then click, i have error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: csrfToken is not defined"
"POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/add_like 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)"

I decided that the problem is in the creation of models Rating, and i tried update view code like this:

```
def add_like(request):

    if request.POST:

        answer_pk = request.POST.get('answer_pk')
        ans_author = Answer.objects.get(pk=answer_pk)

        if Answer.objects.filter(answer=answer_pk) is None:

            Rating.objects.create(user=ans_author.author,
                answer=ans_author.id, like=1, resolve=0)
            data = {'message': 'Success'}

        else:
            ans_rait = Answer.objects.get(answer=answer_pk)
            ans_rait.like += 1
            ans_rait.save()
            data = {'message': 'Success'}

    return JsonResponse(data)

url: url(r'add_like$', views.add_like, name='add_like'),
```

And i have exception: "Answer matching query does not exist"

I think, i confused in logic, now it seems the best solution is add "like" and "solved" pole in Answer model, and then calculate user rating by count of likes and resolve in  AnswerModel. Now my model looks like that:

```
class Answer(models.Model):

    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

Comment: Could you please list the things you've tried? I think the tutorial is pretty clear on how to do this: http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/ajax.html#ajax-based-functionality

Comment: I did all what in guid, but i dont like how its worked in loop. counter is updated on the same button once, on the next, after reload page, and my answer change places after reload.   I have not yet studied js, and tryed first of all build this solution in django only. I think special model for 'likes' would be beter, and if we send data we need method POST, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you want to 'Like' without using AJAX?
There's some stuff wrong with this line:

```
<form method = "post" action = "{% url 'add_like' %}">
```

first of all you don't need all those spaces around the equal-sign. And you'll have to speficy which answer this vote is for, which you'll have to put in the URL. So:

```
<form method="post" action={% url 'add_like' answer.id %}">
```

This will generate the url: `add_like/23/` for example, so answer with id=23 will be updated 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: thank you, it works, but i don't understand how can i update view? In my db rating table all colums are empty, and when i try +=1 like to my model, i have error "Rating matching query does not exist" . I think problem with view

Comment: change `<form method="post" action={% url 'add_like' answer.id %}">` to `<form method="post" action={% url 'add_like' answer.pk %}">`, and change `ans_rait = Rating.objects.get(answer=answer_pk)` to `ans_rait = Rating.objects.get(pk=answer_pk)`

Comment: I tried to add this      `if Answer.objects.filter(answer=answer_pk) is None:
   Rating.objects.create(user=Answer.author,
    answer=Answer.id, like=1, resolve=0)`     `Answer.author` is ForeignKey to CustomUser model

Comment: I can't fully understand because of the formatting of comments - ask your new question at the bottom of your original question and I'll try my best to add an answer to the bottom of my existing answer.

Comment: Hybrid, I update my  Answer,  thank you for helping, i'm really stuck in this problem. Rating and Likes is last big problem of my project, i cant resolve this like 4-5 days, and maybe i just cant fully explain my problem to you, if you dont understand something, i update question like you want

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method = "post" action = "{% url 'add_like' %}">
```

Should be:

```
<form class="_addLike" data-answer-pk="{{ answer.pk }}" method="post" action="{% url 'add_like' %}">
```

So now it's ready for AJAX (put this in the footer):
    
    $('._addLike').on('submit', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var actionURL = $this.attr('action');
        var answerPK= $this.data('answer-pk');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: actionURL,
            data: {'answer_pk': answerPK, 'csrfMiddlewareToken': csrfToken},
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        })
    });

and finally:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def add_like(request):
    if request.POST:
        data = {'message': 'Success'}
        answer_pk = request.POST.get('answer_pk')

        try:
            ans_rait = Rating.objects.get(answer=answer_pk)
        except Rating.DoesNotExist:
            data = {'message': 'Invalid rating obj'}

        if ans_rait:
            ans_rait.like += 1
            ans_rait.save()

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it after other solution. JS is difficult for me, I  have no studied it yet

Comment: **I tried your solution, and I have this exception** : "local variable 'ans_rait' referenced before assignment" **i post js script in console and see this**: "Uncaught ReferenceError: csrfToken is not defined" POST 127.0.0.1:8000/questions/add_like 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)" **I think problem with model Rating, db collumns are empty and we cant get data, i tried update code like this:** `if Answer.objects.filter(answer=answer_pk) is None: Rating.objects.create(answer=Answer.id, like=1, resolve=0)` **Maybe easer add poles "likes" and "resolved" to my `Answer` model?**

Comment: Hybrid, I update my  Answer,  thank you for helping, i'm really stuck in this problem. Rating and Likes is last big problem of my project, i cant resolve this like 4-5 days, and maybe i just cant fully explain my problem to you, if you dont understand something, i update question like you want

Comment: This wont work Hybrid. if Rating.DoesNotExist, it still tries to .like +1 and .save(), even though there is no ans_rait.
You should return a JsonResponse IN the except block

Comment: Nice catch, thanks. Used an if condition instead of a return but that should fix it.